# Which finite solvable groups have solvable automorphism groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups, solvable-groups

Is it possible to give a reasonable description of those finite solvable groups $G$ such that $A = {\rm Aut}(G)$ is also solvable?

The central case to deal with is that in which $G$ is a $p$-group of nilpotence class $2$ (and $G$ may be assumed to be of exponent $p$ if $p$ is odd and exponent dividing $4$ if $p = 2$). All other cases can be reduced to this one: here is a sketch of the argument (via fairly standard group theory):

Firstly, let $G$ be a general finite solvable group, and $A$ be its automorphism group. Let $F = F(G)$ be the Fitting subgroup of $G$, and let $C = C_{A}(F)$. Then $[G,F,C] = [F,C,G] = 1$, so $[C,G,F] = 1$. Hence $[G,C] \leq Z(F)$ and $[G,C,C] = [C,G,C] = 1$. Then $[C,C,G] = 1$ and so $C$ is Abelian. Hence $A$ is solvable if and only if $A/C$ is solvable. But $A/C$ embeds in ${\rm Aut}(F)$. Hence if ${\rm Aut}(F)$ is solvable, then so is $A$.

We are now effectively reduced to the case that $G$ is a $p$-group. Now known results (for example of J.G. Thompson and H. Bender) show that there is a characteristic subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $C_{G}(H) \leq H$ such that $H$ has nilpotence class at most $2$ (and exponent as stated above depending on whether $p$ is odd or $p = 2$) and with $C_{A}(H)$ a $p$-group. Hence if ${\rm Aut}(H)$ is solvable, then so is $A$. This reduces us to the stated case.

Later edit: It might be worth remarking that when $G$ is a solvable group with $\Phi(G) = 1,$ then a priori we can only be sure that ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is solvable when $F(G)$ has cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroups for all primes $p \geq 5$ and $F(G)$ has elementary Abelian Sylow $2$-subgroups of rank at most $2$ and elementary Abelian Sylow $3$-subgroups of rank at most $2.$

Comment: Aren't these groups which have a filtration by characteristic subgroups where the quotient of each group by the next is the additive group of a finite field and the automorphism action on each is via multiplication by elements of that finite field?

Comment: Doesn't the reduction to $p$-groups only go in one direction? $S_3^4$ has solvable automorphism group, but $(\mathbb Z/3)^4$ and $(\mathbb Z/2)^4$ do not.

Comment: @WillSawin : For the first question, you may be right, though I don't see the whole argument myself. As for the second question, yes, I didn't say that it was equivalent to asking the same question for the reduced $p$-groups, the questions are indeed not equivalent. But the conclusion of the outlined argument is that unless $G$ has a class (at most) $2$-characteristic $p$-subgroup $P$ (of exponent $p$ or $4$) with non-solvable automorphism group (and $P$ containing its centralizer in $O_{p}(G)$) , then $G$ has a solvable automorphism group.

Comment: Is there any hope of describing groups of odd order without automorphisms of order 2?

Comment: @MarkSapir: Tht's a nice question, somewhat related to this oone, whose answer I don't know, but others might.

Comment: Just a remark: If $G$ and $Aut(G)$ are solvable, and $G$ acts faithfully and irreducibly on an elementary abelian $p$-group $A$, then the semidirect product $AG$ has solvable automorphism group.

Comment: In the specific case of groups of prime exponent $p$ and nilpotency class $\le p-1$, we boil down to a similar question about nilpotent Lie algebras over $\mathbf{F}_p$, which has no definite answer (even in nilpotency class $2$). In a sense, it is generically the case that the automorphism group is solvable, and the contrary means "lots of symmetry".

Comment: @YCor : Thanks. It is also generically the case that most $p$-groups have outer automorphism group a $p$- group by a reasonable measure, but those which can occur as $O_{p}(G)$ for a reasonably complicated solvable group $G$ must already have fairly complex automorphism groups, so there may still be something to be said in that case.

Comment: I wouldn't say this. For instance, I wouldn't say that a $p$-group of exponent $p$ has generically nilpotency class $\ge 3$, and when the nilp. class is $2$ there is an aut. of order 2. I'm saying generic not necessarily in the sense of counting, but having in mind complex nilpotent Lie algebras (which thus descent on $\mathbf{F}_p$ in some way, unique or not). The variety of nilpotent $d$-dimensional Lie algebras has several connected components, so there is no "genericity" in some sense. Nevertheless I expect no whole component consists of algebras with non-solvable derivation Lie algebra.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I asked https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351715/automorphism-groups-of-odd-order .